# jquery sortable ui exceptions

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-sortable

I am getting following error, when I sorts/rearrange div **QUICKLY**.

```
TypeError: this.placeholder[0].parentNode is null
```

JQuery UI is the API, that I am using: http://jqueryui.com/sortable/

```
$("#contents").sortable({
    beforeStop: function (event, ui) {
        console.log("BeforeStop Fn Invoked:Parent Node Val:  " + $(ui.placeholder).parent()[0]);
        if (typeof ($(ui.placeholder).parent()[0]) === 'undefined') {
            console.log("If condition passed: " + ($(ui.placeholder).parent()[0]));
            $("#contents").sortable('cancel');
        }
        console.log("BeforeStop Fn Terminates");
    },
    stop: function (event, ui) {
        console.log("Inside Stop Function");
        var op = $(this).sortable('toArray');
        for (i = 0; i < result.length; i++) {
            result[i] = result[i].replace('-sn', '');
        }
        var contents_identifier = JSON.stringify(op);
        $.post(baseurl + 'index.php', {
            para1: contents_identifier
        },

        function (data) {
            fill_content_table();
        });
        console.log("Stop Fun Terminated\n");
    }
}).disableSelection();
```

Whenever I gets above error, this is what the console at Firebug prints:

```
##################################################################
BeforeStop Fn Invoked: Parent Node Val:  undefined
If condition passed: undefined
BeforeStop Fn Terminates
TypeError: this.placeholder[0].parentNode is null
```

I guess the exception or above error occus, as soon as the stop function is executed(as I can't see the debug statement **Inside Stop Function**).

Tried few things, like delaying the executions. But it did n't work.
Any help is appreciated.

UPD:
Please note, following is the console output in case of SUCCESS:

```
##################################################################
BeforeStop Fn Invoked: Parent Node Val:  [object HTMLDivElement]

BeforeStop Fn Terminates
Inside Stop Function

POST https://www. 200 OK 730ms  
Stop Fun Terminated
####################################################
POST https:www.........200 OK 734ms
```

Answer (score 0):

You need quotes around `ui.placeholder` as `$('ui.placeholder')`